# Get Group Match in re.sub in Python

Tags: python, regex, perl

In Perl, it is possible for me to do a substitution and capture a group match at the same time. e.g.

```
my $string = "abcdef123";
$string =~ s/(\d+)//;
my $groupMatched = $1; # $groupMatched is 123
```

In Python, I can do the substitution using re.sub function as follows. However, I cannot find a way to capture the \d+ group match without invoking another function re.match and performing an additional operation.

```
string = "abcdef123"
string = re.sub("(\d+)", "", string)
```

Does anyone know how I can capture the "\d+" matched value as a separate variable from the same re.sub operation? I tried the following command and it doesn't work.

```
print r'\1'
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible (at least at the same time) because the return object of `re.sub` is a string. If you have something like this `rx_obj = re.search('123$', another_string)`, you get an RE object which can be captured by `rx_obj.group()`.

Comment: Guess you might be right that it is not possible to do both at the same time. The other ways seem a bit hackish or are basically two separate steps.

Comment: Note that in Perl, you should always verify if your match succeeded before using the special numbered variables: `if ($str =~ s/(\d+)//){ $x = $1; }`

Answer (score 16):

You can cheat and pass a function to `re.sub`:

```
results = []
def capture_and_kill(match):
    results.append(match)
    return ""
string = "abcdef123"
string = re.sub("(\d+)", capture_and_kill, string)
results[0].group(1)
# => '123'
```

Comment: ```results[0].group()[1]```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
sub_str = re.search("(\d+)", str).group(1)
```

Will find the "123" part.

Then you replace it:

```
str = str.replace(sub_str, "")
```

Note that if you have more than [0-9] sequence you'll need to use `findall` and iterate manually on all matches.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, or at least not very general - you can't assume that finding `sub_str` as a string is the same as finding the original pattern as a regular expression.  For example, if the pattern was `r"foo(?!bar)"`, it will match `"foobarfoo"` only at position 6, but the matched string `"foo"` appears at positions 0 and 6.

Answer (score -3):

below code tested under python 3.6.

```
test = "abcdef123"
resp = re.sub(r'\w+[A-Za-z](\d+)',r'\1',test)
print (resp)

123
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it just happens to return the same string as `\1` because your replacement pattern is `r'\1'`.